# Assignment to the result of a function changes variable

Tags: r

Looking through the `ave` function, I found a remarkable line:

```
split(x, g) <- lapply(split(x, g), FUN) # From ave
```

Interestingly, this line changes the value of `x`, which I found unexpected. I expected that `split(x,g)` would result in a list, which could be assigned to, but discarded afterward. My question is, why does the value of `x` change?

Another example may explain better:

```
a <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2), value=c(4,5,7,6))
#   id value
# 1  1     4
# 2  1     5
# 3  2     7
# 4  2     6

split(a,a$id) # Split a row-wise by id into a list of size 2
# $`1`
#   id value
# 1  1     4
# 2  1     5
# $`2`
#   id value
# 3  2     7
# 4  2     6

# Find the row with highest value for each id
lapply(split(a,a$id),function(x) x[which.max(x$value),])
# $`1`
#   id value
# 2  1     5
# $`2`
#   id value
# 3  2     7

# Assigning to the split changes the data.frame a!
split(a,a$id)<-lapply(split(a,a$id),function(x) x[which.max(x$value),])
a
#   id value
# 1  1     5
# 2  1     5
# 3  2     7
# 4  2     7
```

Not only has `a` changed, but it changed to a value that does not look like the right hand side of the assignment! Even if assigning to `split(a,a$id)` somehow changes `a` (which I don't understand), why does it result in a `data.frame` instead of a `list`?

Note that I understand that there are better ways to accomplish this task. My question is why does `split(a,a$id)<-lapply(split(a,a$id),function(x) x[which.max(x$value),])` change `a`?

Comment: The function you're calling is `split<-`, not `split`.  They're two different functions.  Look at `split<-.default` and it's obvious why `a` changes.

Comment: And you have to use backquotes to print the function because the function name contains an operator: `\`split<-.default\``.

Comment: I this case, wouldn't the relevant function be `\`split<-.data.frame\``?

Comment: Yes, it would but the function definitions are almost identical, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help page for split says in its header: "The replacement forms replace values corresponding to such a division." So it really should not be unexpected, although I admit it is not widely used. I do not understand how your example illustrates that the assigned values "do not look like the RHS of the assignment!". The max values are assigned to the 'value' lists within categories defined by the second argument factor.

(I do thank you for the question. I had not realized that `split<-` was at the core of `ave`. I guess it is more widely used than I realized, since I think `ave` is a wonderfully useful function.)

Comment: I see. My issue was that I didn't realize that `split<-` was itself a function. I suspect that this function can be used for some very clever, concise, and efficient code. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just after definition of `a`, perform `split(a, a$id)=1`, the result would be:

```
> a
  id value
1  1     1
2  1     1
3  1     1
4  1     1
```

Comment: `split` does not return results by reference.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that split<- actually modified the LHS  with RHS values.

Here's an example:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3);
> split(x,x==2)
$`FALSE`
[1] 1 3
$`TRUE`
[1] 2
> split(x,x==2) <- split(c(10,20,30),c(10,20,30)==20)
> x
[1] 10 20 30
```

Note the line where I re-assign `split(x,x==2) <-` . This actually reassigns `x`.

As the comments below have stated, you can look up the definition of `split<-` like so

```
> `split<-.default`
function (x, f, drop = FALSE, ..., value) 
{
    ix <- split(seq_along(x), f, drop = drop, ...)
    n <- length(value)
    j <- 0
    for (i in ix) {
        j <- j%%n + 1
        x[i] <- value[[j]]
    }
    x
}
<bytecode: 0x1e18ef8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: `split<-` is what's being called and it's written in R.

Comment: How would you display the code for that. At least for split, I can just type "split", and it outputs: 
function (x, f, drop = FALSE, ...) 
UseMethod("split")
<bytecode: 0x1fd29f8>
<environment: namespace:base>

Comment: And to add to what Joshua says split (on the RHS)  _does_ return values, and does NOT pass by reference.

Comment: You have to use backquotes because the function name contains an operator. `\`split<-.default\``

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: How are you getting backticks to display properly in comments?

Comment: @DWin: escape them with a backslash.